# How to listen for messages from sockets in Sails.js?

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, sails.js

So I want to listen to messages that I get from sockets in my Sails.js app. How can I achieve that?

Is there something like socket.io on method?

Answer (score 3):

*There is exactly something like the socket.io `on` method.*

**Take a look in here:** http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/websockets/resourceful-pubsub

---

Here's a little example.

Let's say you are using `Model.message` to [broadcast your messages](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/websockets/resourceful-pubsub/message.html), and are using [Sails' Socket Client](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/websockets/sails.io.js).

In this example, we're going to assume that:

- Your controller route is: `/messageStream`
- The model you're using is: `User`

In order to listen for messages, you must first subscribe to the context. So let's go on...

**Subscribing in your controller:**

```
User.subscribe(req.socket, { id: req.user.id }, 'message');
```

The *first parameter* is the request socket, the *second one* is the list of users you want to subscribe to the context(s) (in this example, only one user) and *the third one* is the context(s) you want to subscribe to, which in this case is only the `message` context.

**Listening for messages in your client:**

```
io.socket.get('/messageStream');
io.socket.on('user', function(obj) {
    if(obj.verb === 'messaged') {
        console.log(obj);
        // Do something fun with the message object!       
    }
});
```

The parameter in `io.socket.get` is your controller's route.

The first parameter in `io.socket.on` is *your model's name in lowercase*.

Notice that when you receive a message, the object received comes with the `messaged` verb.

...And that's pretty much it.

Comment: You can do this only in an action from the controller.